# Delete Only First Zero in Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

ch.value values 00 , 01 , 02 , 03.
It must be 0 , 1 , 2 , 3.
I'am using this code :

```
Concat_ws('_', ch.prop, Trim(LEADING '0' FROM ch.value))
```

This code does not work at 00 case , how can i fix it ?

Comment: I certainly hope you are not storing multiple **numbers** in a delimited **string**.  If so, you should fix the data model, not try to format the numbers within the strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This will create the workload for me. Already I am just having trouble with the double zero case that I mentioned.

Comment: `0 + ch.value`?

Comment: Can't you just cast them to an integer?

Comment: @Nick intelligently!

Comment: 00 can occur anywhere in string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below condition:

```
Concat_ws('_', ch.prop, case when left(ch.value,1)='0' then substring(ch.value,2) end)
```